# Delete all folders with specific name on ntfs drive

Tags: macos, ntfs

I have a windows partition on my mac on which I want to delete all folders named "bower_components" or "node_modules" and all of its subfolders.

It is already mounted via ParagonNTFS so that I have read and write permissions.

How can I bulk delete these folders recursively from the terminal without moving them to trash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` offers the ability to combine file identifiers and pass these to an external command like this, in your case:

```
find /Volumes/NTFS_part -type d \( -name bower_components -or -name node_modules \) -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

*Explanation:*

- The first argument is the starting point for the search. I used the OS X convention of /Volumes
- `-type d` will restrict the search to files of type directory
- the escaped parenthesis contain the search filters to use. NOTE that the identifier is repeated within the parenthesis
- the `-exec` argument allow the results, referred to with the curly braces, to be used in an external command. When using `-exec`, you must terminate the external command with an escaped semi-colon so that `find` knows where the command ends.

***Caveat Emptor:*** Using a delete command in this manner can be very dangerous. Please read, test carefully and take the usual precautions.

Comment: thanks. i replaced `rm rf` with `print` before executing the command to make sure that only the desired folders are on the list